# If checkbox is checked, check another box

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to create a few checkboxes that when checked, will check another... which I got to work! But, the problem I'm having now is that if multiple are selected and one is unchecked at any point, the additional checkbox get unchecked no matter what. I'd like to find a way to have the additional checkbox stay checked, as long as one of the others is, and uncheck if none are selected.

For example: I have 4 checkboxes, if a user selects #1 I want to check #2. Or if a user selects #1 + #3, check #2, but if #3 is unchecked, #2 stays as long as 1,3, or 4 are. I hope this makes sense. I've been trying different things, but this is the code where I landed. Any help, advice on a better way to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var chk1 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='1']");
var chk2 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='2']");
var chk3 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='3']");
var chk4 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='4']");

chk1.on('change', function(){
  chk2.prop('checked',this.checked);
});
chk3.on('change', function(){
  chk2.prop('checked',this.checked);
});
chk4.on('change', function(){
  chk2.prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="user_name">1
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="user_name">2
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" class="user_name">3
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" class="user_name">4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep `chk2` checked until all others are unchecked, you have to look for the status of all other boxes in each event handler. Ideally, you would create a function for that, so you don't need to repeat your code for all handlers.

```
function toggleChk2() {
  let check2 = (chk1.is(':checked') ||
      chk3.is(':checked') ||
      chk4.is(':checked'))
  chk2.prop('checked',check2);
}

chk1.on('change', function(){
  toggleChk2();
});
chk2.on('change', function(){
  toggleChk2();
});
chk3.on('change', function(){
  toggleChk2();
});
chk4.on('change', function(){
  toggleChk2();
});
```

You can also add this function to the change handler of `chk2` if you want to prevent manual change of that checkbox.

Comment: Ah, this is great and works perfectly! Thank you so much!! Although this answer is exactly what I was looking for, I didn't think about the fact that this "disables" the 2nd checkbox from being checked/unchecked by itself. I'm trying to tweak it, but is there a way that would allow that to be selected on its own, but still function in the same manner with the rest?

Comment: Yeah, just remove the evenhandler for `chk2.on('change')` ...

Answer (score 1):

For the record: alternative without JQuery, using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and a css selector to query the state of the other checkboxes:

```js
[`change`, `click`].forEach( evtType => 
  document.addEventListener(evtType, handle) );

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.closest(`.user_name`)) {
    const cb2 = document.querySelector(`.user_name[value="2"]`);
    const oneOfOthersChecked = 
      document.querySelector(`.user_name:not([value="2"]):is(:checked)`);
    return cb2.checked = !!oneOfOthersChecked || cb2.checked;
  }
  if (evt.target.id === "empty") {
    return document.querySelectorAll(`.user_name:checked`)
      .forEach(cb => cb.checked = !cb.checked);
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="user_name">1
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="user_name">2
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" class="user_name">3
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" class="user_name">4
<br>
<button id="empty">Uncheck all</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit overkill, but you could define the "dependencies" inside a structure.

```js
// Map contents displayed using object notation
const dependenciesOf = Map{
  "chk1": ["chk2"],
  "chk3": ["chk2"],
  "chk4": ["chk2"],
  "chk5": ["chk1", "chk4"]
}
```

With this structure defined we can programmatically build a reverse index.

```js
// Map contents displayed using object notation
const requiredBy = Map{
  "chk1": ["chk5"],
  "chk2": ["chk1", "chk3", "chk4"],
  "chk4": ["chk5"]
}
```

With these 2 structures defined we can use the following `change` event handler:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function () {
  const dependencies = dependenciesOf.get(this.id) || [];
  for (const dependency of dependencies) {
    if (this.checked) {
      // mark the dependency as checked and disable interaction
      $(`#${dependency}`).prop("disabled", true).prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
    } else {
      // enable the dependency interaction whenever the dependency is no longer required
      const ids = requiredBy.get(dependency) || [];
      const isRequired = ids.some(id => $(`#${id}`).prop("checked"));
      if (!isRequired) $(`#${dependency}`).prop("disabled", false);
    }
  }
});
```

This will mark all the relevant dependencies as *checked* and will disable the user interaction as long as it's required by another checkbox.

The reason we `.trigger("change")` after changing the *checked* value, is to recursively check dependencies. If we don't do this `chk5` would only check `chk1` and `chk4`, but not `chk2`.

```js
// define dependencies (based on element ID)
const dependenciesOf = new Map([
  ["chk1", ["chk2"]], // checkbox 1 requires checkbox 2 to be set
  ["chk3", ["chk2"]], // checkbox 3 requires checkbox 2 to be set
  ["chk4", ["chk2"]], // checkbox 4 requires checkbox 2 to be set
  ["chk5", ["chk1", "chk4"]], // checkbox 5 requires checkbox 1 and 4 to be set
]);

// programatically build a reverse index of the dependencies
const requiredBy = new Map();
for (const [checkbox, dependencies] of dependenciesOf) {
  for (const dependency of dependencies) {
    if (!requiredBy.has(dependency)) requiredBy.set(dependency, []);
    requiredBy.get(dependency).push(checkbox);
  }
}

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function () {
  const dependencies = dependenciesOf.get(this.id) || [];
  for (const dependency of dependencies) {
    if (this.checked) {
      // mark the dependency as checked and disable interaction
      $(`#${dependency}`).prop("disabled", true).prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
    } else {
      // enable the dependency interaction whenever the dependency is no longer required
      const ids = requiredBy.get(dependency) || [];
      const isRequired = ids.some(id => $(`#${id}`).prop("checked"));
      if (!isRequired) $(`#${dependency}`).prop("disabled", false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" value="1" /><label for="chk1">1</label><br />
<input id="chk2" type="checkbox" value="2" /><label for="chk2">2</label><br />
<input id="chk3" type="checkbox" value="3" /><label for="chk3">3</label><br />
<input id="chk4" type="checkbox" value="4" /><label for="chk4">4</label><br />
<input id="chk5" type="checkbox" value="5" /><label for="chk5">5</label><br />
```

I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for, but I hope this gives you at least some inspiration.